# Convergence of the sequence $\frac{1}{e^k \sin{k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, transcendental-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Does the sequence $\frac{1}{e^k \sin{k}}$ converge?

If $\sin{k}$ acts as a random variable (taking on values in $(-1, 1)$), then it seems like we should be able to prove that the sequence converges with high probability. I wonder if it can be decided absolutely.

Comment: $$-\frac{1}{e^k}\leq\frac{\sin k}{e^k}\leq\frac{1}{e^k}$$ hence your sequence converges to zero by squeezing. The behaviour of $\sin k$ does not really matter here.

Comment: I changed the question above - the current form is what I intended to ask about.

Comment: This is way more subtle. The limit is still zero since $\pi$ has a finite irrationality measure.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The sequence is $\dfrac{1}{e^k\sin k}$ and not $\dfrac{\sin k}{e^k}$?

Comment: Yes, the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{e^k\sin k}\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to zero because $\pi$ has a finite irrationality measure. Even assuming that $k$ goes close to a multiple of $\pi$, it cannot go so close that $e^k \sin k$ stay bounded for infinite times.

Comment: Indeed, this is a nice, subtle question now. But the limit should be zero.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Since $e^k$ is an overkill is there an elementary proof that doesn't use the irrationality measure?

Comment: @Conifold: I was wondering the same thing, but honestly I don't know. Maybe we can exploit the fact that $e^k\sin k=\Im\left(\exp(i+1)^k\right)$, or just compute $\sum_{k=A}^{B}e^k \sin k$ to extrapolate some relevant information. I will think about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It converges to $0$, in fact $\frac{1}{k^7\sin{k}}$ already converges to $0$, see Theorem 2 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5100v1.pdf). This theorem gives a nice characterization of the [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of $\pi$ as the borderline number $\mu$ such that $\frac{1}{k^{u-1}\sin{k}}$ converges to $0$ for $u>\mu$, and diverges for $u<\mu$. So $\frac{1}{k^7\sin{k}}$ converges because $\mu$ is known to be less than $8$, and $\frac{1}{k^{1/2}\sin{k}}$ diverges because it has to be at least $2$. Whether $\frac{1}{k^2\sin{k}}$ converges is an open question, but the [conventional wisdom](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178811/lower-bound-on-the-irrationality-measure-of-pi) is that $\mu=2$.

Interestingly enough, the sequence $\frac{1}{k^{u-1}\xi_k}$, where $\xi_k$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$ converges to $0$ almost surely if and only if $\sum\frac{1}{k^{u-1}}<\infty$. So $\sin{k}$ being a "random variable" uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$ is in fact equivalent to $\mu=2$.

Convergence of similar sequences $\frac{\tan k}{k^{u-1}}$ is analysed [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf), also implicitly using the irrationality measure of $\pi$.

Answer (score -1):

NOT A PROOF. But here are my thoughts. I don't think it will converge. As k continues to get larger, it will hit closer and closer multiples of pi. For example, k=3, 31, 314, 3141, 31415, ... etc. As these values of k occur, sin(k) will get closer and closer to zero. Since sin(k) is in the denominator, the effect will cause the $k^{th}$ sequence element to get bumpy, which happens when one divides by zero (or numbers close to zero). Yes, there is the $e^{k}$ in the denominator that makes the sequence appear to converge quickly, but again those approximate multiples of pi become more accurate as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

[image]

This picture shows what happens at $x=\pi, 2\pi,...$ , and what will happen as the values of k get closer to a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: I believe that doesn't actually solve the problem - your flaw is in assuming sin(3), sin(31), sin(314), ... get closer and closer to zero when in reality the arguments aren't getting closer to a multiple of $\pi$. Good thought though.

Comment: @TannyLibman Surely as the sequence progresses, we will get $k = 314159\ldots$ of arbitrary length, which is pretty close to a multiple of $\pi$?

Comment: @Zach These $k$ will get close to a multiple of $\pi$ if "close" refers to a ratio, but not if it refers to a difference, and the latter is more important in this problem.  For example,$$31415926535=10000000000\pi-0.8979\ ,$$and the sine of this number is $-0.7820$ which is not very close to zero.

Comment: For $\sin(k)$ close to $0$, it is much better to use the numerators in [convergents of $\pi$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiContinuedFraction.html). The first few convergents of $\pi$ are $3, 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, \ldots$. In particular, $1/\sin(355) \sim -33173.70878965024$ is surprisingly large.